# Transfer Learning Argument Error: Invalid argument: channels must be 0 or 3 for GIF, got 1?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer

I am doing transfer learning with Keras and got a weird argument error.

I don't understand what's going on? Is my image loader missing something, I don't see a channel problem in my code. It is crashing during the training, during the beginning of the first epoch.

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  channels must be 0 or 3 for GIF, got 1
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_7]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  channels must be 0 or 3 for GIF, got 1
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_111601]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

My input is (28,28,1)

My image loader:

```
image_size=(28,28)
num_classes = 29
batch_size=32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "/content/Products", labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    class_names=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=batch_size, image_size=image_size,
     shuffle=True, seed=seed, validation_split=0.2, subset="training",
    interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False
)
```

[image: My first layer]

My Model

````
def make_transfer_model(reconstructed_model,num_classes):

   new_layer = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')

   transfer_model = keras.Model(reconstructed_model.input,new_layer(reconstructed_model.layers[-2].output))

   return transfer_model
```
````

Comment: reduce `batch_size=32`, you can try with a lower `batch size`

Comment: I reduced the batch size down to 8, still have the same issue. It is crashing during the training

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow can't read `GIF` images with a number of channel specified to 1 (i.e `colour_mode="grayscale"`).

A short example with that image `cat.gif` :

[image]

If we try to read the image with a number of channel set to 1, we get an `InvalidArgumentError`. (The following snippet is how `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` read images, you can check the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py#L231)):

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> img_bytes = tf.io.read_file("cat.gif")
>>> img_decoded = tf.io.decode_image(img_bytes, channels=1)
InvalidArgumentError: channels must be 0 or 3 for GIF, got 1 [Op:DecodeImage]**
```

Convert your `GIF`s to `PNG`, `BMP` or `JPG` to be able to use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` with `colour_mode="grayscale"`.

---

Image source: ["File:Odd-eyed cat by ihasb33r-2.gif"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=10585418) by [Odd-eyed_cat_by_ihasb33r.jpg: ihasb33r derivative work: Jasonwjones (talk)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Odd-eyed_cat_by_ihasb33r.jpg) is licensed under CC BY-SA 2.0

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The weird thing is that my images are in JPG.

Comment: There are no GIF images in my dataset.. Is there a way to force tensorflow to detect those images as JPG?

Comment: A `.jpg` extension is not enough to say that an image is a jpg. TF checks the magic number in the header, so it's unlikely it is wrong. You can check the real type of your file with [`imghdr.what`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html). There are probably some gif with a jpg extension hiding in your data.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have corrupted files, or images with a type not supported by tensorflow.

Comment: Is there a way to convert my folder and subfolders of images from GIF to JPG ?

Comment: You can do that with a combination of `PIL` and `pathlib`